# TCP/IP Communication Protocol used by hyperterminal?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, qt4, communication

Can anyone tell me which **Communication Protocol** is used by hyperterminal connecting via **Tcp/Ip** ?

**Protocol** here means **UDP**, **Socket/Server**, other(If any).

Actually, I need to design an application **(in QT, Linux as OS)** to communicate to a machine (basically a printer) **via Ethernet**. I need to send request to the printer as well as receive response, if any, from the printer.

It can be communicated via Hyperterminal using Tcp/IP.

So I wonder which protocol should i use for the communication. As Printer simply supports ethernet therefore I have no idea, if I can use Socket/Server for communication.

Need suggestion over this. All idea/suggestion are welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you read wikipage on [HyperTerminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperTerminal)?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Yes, I read wiki page. But couldn't find out the solution.

Comment: A printer usually has an Ethernet device to support some higher level protocol (e.g. TCP/IP, perhaps using CUPS or FTP). I suggest diving into the documentation of HyperTerminal and of your printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your terminology right.  TCP/IP and UDP are **transport** layers. A **protocol** refers to the application data that is transmitted over a **transport**.  A socket is a **programming API** that allows an application to gain access to a **transport** so it can send/receive **protocol** data.

Now, to answer your question - HyperTerminal typically uses the Telnet protocol over TCP/IP.  Many protocols in existence are text-based, and Telnet is largely compatible with simple ASCII text, which makes it convenient for allowing users to use Telnet UI clients, like HyperTerminal, to manually send text commands to network-connected devices.  However, most devices/protocols do not use the actual Telnet protocol.  But if you can communicate with a device using HyperTerminal, you can code your app to send/receive the same text commands.